# Is there any way to configure what info is displayed in the tiles view of windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-management, desktop-customization

[image: Windows Explorer Tile View in Windows 7]

The Tiles View in Windows Explorer displays the file name with 2 other lines of information about the file. As you can see in the image, the information displayed depends on the file. Executable programs are the ones that vary the most, but other than that and folders (see gif, jpg, png files in the image), usually the lines displayed are:

```
filename.ext
File Type Description
### KB
```

If you already have it set to show extensions in the filename, you might think that displaying the File Type Description is redundant. I'd like to use that space to show, for example, the modified date instead, so I don't have to use Contents or Details view just for that.

I'm pretty sure that there is a setting for that in Ubuntu, but is there any way to configure this in Windows 7? If not with a setting, maybe through the registry or some program?

I'd like to change only the default info that is displayed - exe files and the like should still retain their behavior of diplaying whatever is more relevant.

Comment: No customization possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes is possible.

Write **TileInfo** string value under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\somefiletype** points to

*Prop:[flags]PropertyCanonicalName;[flags]PropertyCanonicalName;*

See [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/building-property-handlers-property-lists) for reference.

Comment: This works, though you have to do it for each separate file extension, which you'll find under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations. Also, you're limited to 2 properties, unlike the 3 that the MSDN reference says.